# How can I get position and type of Handle in bezier curve?

Tags: python

I want to get a position and handle the type of specific spline

[image]

as you know there are some types

[image]

for example, I want to get point 1 type and position

```
position = Vector(2.0, 0.0, 0.0)
type = 'ALIGNED'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

based on [bezier spline point documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.BezierSplinePoint.html) and [this useful blog](http://pymove3d.pysv.org/python_course/stories/python/blender-moves/f-path-overview/)

you can get the position of handle by `handle_left` and `handle_right`

**Handl positions**
handle_left
handle_right

you can get handle type by `handle_left_type` and `handle_right_type`

**Handle types**

```
 enum in [‘FREE’, ‘VECTOR’, ‘ALIGNED’, ‘AUTO’], default ‘FREE’
```

so you can get them easily

```
import bpy

# Type of the first handle        
print(bpy.data.curves['BezierCurve'].splines[0].bezier_points[0].handle_left_type)

# Type of the second handle
print(bpy.data.curves['BezierCurve'].splines[0].bezier_points[0].handle_right_type)

# Coordinates of the first handle 
print(bpy.data.curves['BezierCurve'].splines[0].bezier_points[0].handle_left)

# Coordinates of the second handle
print(bpy.data.curves['BezierCurve'].splines[0].bezier_points[0].handle_right)
```

[image]

Comment: Consider for the second part of code using the python console, which will echo the value.

Comment: @batFINGER I attached an Image as you can see it works on console

Comment: Can select and copy text from console.  Simply typing in the path eg `D.curves['BezierCurve'].splines[0].bezier_points[0].handle_right`will echo result back to console.